# MongoDB NULL Pointer Exception while getting JSON as input

Tags: java, mongodb, database

```
package com.demo.mongodb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;

public class Driver {
    private static DBCollection channelDBcollection;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DB db = (new MongoClient("localhost",27017)).getDB("demo");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        boolean flag = false;
        while(!flag) flag = autenticate(db, bufferedReader);
    }
    private static boolean autenticate(DB db, BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws IOException{
        boolean flag = true;
        System.out.println("User: ");
        String user = bufferedReader.readLine();

        System.out.println("Password: ");
        String password = bufferedReader.readLine();

        if(db.authenticate(user, password.toCharArray())){
            DBCollection channDbCollection = db.getCollection("Channel");
            String command = null;
            while(true){
                System.out.println("What do you want to do ? ");
                command = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if(command.equals("exit")) break ;
                else if(command.equals("findALL")) findAll(channDbCollection);
                else if(command.equals("insertJSON")) insertJSON(bufferedReader,channDbCollection);
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("invalid user/password");
            flag = false;
        }


        return flag;
    }

    private static void findAll(DBCollection dbCollection){
        DBCursor dbCursor = channelDBcollection.find();
        while(dbCursor.hasNext()) System.out.println(dbCursor.next());
    }

    private static void insertJSON(BufferedReader bufferedReader,DBCollection channDbCollection) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("JSON: ");
        channDbCollection.insert((DBObject) JSON.parse(bufferedReader.readLine()));
    }
}
```

**I make Database in MongoDB like :-**

> use demo
>
> db.addUser("root","root")

While i executed application then while i enter for JSON , i found null pointer can someone help me to take out of this ?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and highlight which line in your code the exception is happening?

Comment: it's showing on this:-                                                  DBCursor dbCursor = channelDBcollection.find();

Comment: Can you still post the stack trace? Are you sure your DBCollection channDbCollection is not null?

Answer (score 0):

in your

```
private static void findAll(DBCollection dbCollection){
    DBCursor dbCursor = channelDBcollection.find();
    while(dbCursor.hasNext()) System.out.println(dbCursor.next());
}
```

function, you use global variable channelDBcollection (which is null at the time of call) instead of parameter dbCollection (which is not used anywhere in the method);
what you think is "not null" is the local variable with confusing name "channDbCollection", but it's not used anywhere;

I suggest you to revise your approach to naming, using global variables and coding style in general.